# weka 'predictions on test split' not listed in same order as data

Tags: weka

Consider the following fictional arff file:

```
@relation referents
@attribute feature1      NUMERIC
@attribute feature2      NUMERIC
@attribute feature3      NUMERIC
@attribute feature4      NUMERIC
@attribute class{WIN,LOSS}
@data
1, 7, 1, 0, WIN
1, 5, 1, 0, WIN
-1, 1, 1, 0, LOSS
1, 1, 1, 1, WIN
-1, 1, 1, 1, WIN
1, 7, 1, 0, WIN
1, 5, 1, 0, WIN
-1, 1, 1, 0, LOSS
1, 1, 1, 1, WIN
-1, 1, 1, 1, WIN
```

Using WEKA 3-8, open the above ARFF in Explorer. Click on Classify. Select J48 classifier, keeping all default settings. 
Under Test Options, select Percentage split = 50%
Click More Options, select Output Predictions->CSV

Click start

You will see the following output:

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2
Relation:     referents
Instances:    10
Attributes:   5
              feature1
              feature2
              feature3
              feature4
              class
Test mode:    split 50.0% train, remainder test

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

J48 pruned tree
------------------

feature1 <= -1
|   feature4 <= 0: LOSS (2.0)
|   feature4 > 0: WIN (2.0)
feature1 > -1: WIN (6.0)

Number of Leaves  :     3

Size of the tree :  5


Time taken to build model: 0 seconds

=== Predictions on test split ===

inst#,actual,predicted,error,prediction
1,2:LOSS,1:WIN,+,0.8
2,1:WIN,1:WIN,,0.8
3,1:WIN,1:WIN,,0.8
4,1:WIN,1:WIN,,0.8
5,1:WIN,1:WIN,,0.8
```

// skipping the rest of the report...

Observe that the last five instances in the input arff file are in the order

WIN
WIN
LOSS
WIN
WIN

However, the actual output 'predictions on test split' is in the order:
LOSS
WIN
WIN
WIN
WIN

Why are these not in the same order, and also, how is one supposed to make the connection between the inst# in 'predictions on test split' and the @data instance in the arff file?

Answer (score 0):

When weka split your data into train and test, it generates randomly, which means weka randomly selects instances from your arff (you can also specify the applied random).  Thats why the order is different from the last 5 instances.

Comment: There must be a way to preserve the order - otherwise the predictive functionality is not helpful. In fact, the output of the J48 classifier  'predictions on test split' cannot be traced back to the original instance without it.

Comment: It is not clear why you want preserve the order, and why you think " the predictive functionality is not helpful". 
It is totally not clear why you want to track back the predicitions?
If you want the index of instances, why not define an attribute for it? or, if you know that all your last x instances are the tests, why not split your dataset manually into train and test?